# How to add a loader in a Vue/Webpack app to support non JS files used in a dependency of a node module

Tags: vue.js, webpack, coffeescript, psd, webpack-loader

I have a Vue 2 app that uses Webpack, and I am trying to use in it the node module PSD.js, which in itself utilizes CoffeeScript as part of it's dependencies. When I try to compile i get the error:

`Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,`

referring to the the file `./node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js` that PSD.js installed as part of it's dependencies when I did `npm install psd`.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

I understand I need to tell the Vue app how to handle .coffee files with a loader, but I have tried installing coffee-loader, coffee, set the vue.config.js to:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "./",
  configureWebpack: {
    target: "node-webkit",
    node: false,
    module: {
      rules: [
        // ...
        {
          test: /\.coffee$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'coffee-loader'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  lintOnSave: false
};
```

yet still nothing works, I get the same error. I feel it is because I am not using CoffeeScript directly but rather a node module that I AM using, psd.js, is the one using it. That is why I cannot set `lang="coffee"` in the script tag attribute of my Vue module (I am using vanilla JS to run everything).

thnx in advance

ADDING MORE INFO:
I use a boilerplate framework to setup my app, and it initialises the vue/webpack app for me indirectly.

To reproduce, and even though this system is for Adobe plugins, you do **not** need the Adobe host app to see the issue, do:

```
npm install -g bombino
```

Then in a folder of your choosing run:

```
bombino
```

and fill in these params when asked:

```
? Name of panel? Hello World
? Use your custom templates or bombino defaults? Bombino
What tooling preset should be used? Vue-CLI
? Which Vue-CLI template should be used? bombino-vue-bare (Absolute minimum)
? Host apps to include: After Effects
? Base CEF Port (between 1024 and 65534) 8666
? Run npm install for you? Yes
```

then cd into `Hello-World` and run `npm run serve`. You should see the app is compiled correctly and is running on some port (8080 or higher if taken).

Now go back to the root folder and install psd.js: `npm install psd`
then go back into `Hello-World` and run `npm run serve` again. This time it will fail to compile with the error I started this question with. Even if you go and install `coffee-loader` by doing `npm install --save coffeescript coffee-loader` and change the `vue.config.js` to be like so:

```
  publicPath: "./",
  // Thanks Eric Robinson
  configureWebpack: {
    target: "node-webkit", // Set the target to node-webkit (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/)
    node: false, // Don't set certain Node globals/modules to empty objects (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/),
    module: {
      rules: [
        // ...
        {
          test: /\.coffee$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'coffee-loader'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  lintOnSave: false
};
```

or if you do `vue use coffee` - all of these result in the same error: the compiler/packager doesn't know how to handle the .coffee file (used as a dependency by psd.js).

Thnx again to anyone who has info

Comment: From some minimal testing, it seems that PSD.js library is not very browser friendly, installing it through NPM doesn't include built files that would allow it to be run in the browser.

Even if you got coffee script to work, it would fail due to it not being compatible with browser (uses path, fs node modules). If you want to add coffee script you can run the vue cli command: `vue add coffee`

You may wanna try using the version in this [pull request](https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js/pull/150) or just include the `psd.js` from `dist` folder in your project without using node_modules.

Comment: thnx @Mkalo actually the app will run in a CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework), specifically it is an Adobe plugin - that supports much more than a browser, node included, fs, etc... so I am not worried about coffee etc...
I am just trying to see how to correctly define the loader so that webpack knows how to handle the coffee files

Comment: Then running `vue add coffee` should already do the work, that's how I tested the library and got errors with fs and path. If you want to manually add it with webpack you could also check what `vue-cli-plugin-coffee` is doing internally for it to work.

Comment: thnx, but nothing works for me. I added more info in the original question, since I used some boilerplate framework to setup my app.